# Oracle Passing table variables

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I am new to Oracle Stored Procedure.  I have written the below stored procedure and giving results.

I believe the table variable and parameter variable or same name. How to handle this case without changing the variable names.O

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedval (Code IN varchar(50),Id1 OUT INTE)
AS
BEGIN

 Id1 := 0;

SELECT Id1 INTO id1
FROM tabl1
WHERE Code = Code;

END;
```

Comment: try using "id1" for the column name (with the double quotes)

Comment: What is an "INTE?"  Also, there is no size declaration for parameters (unless you use a subtype), so remove "(50)"  Good practice not to name parameters same as columns.  Try prefixing, such as P_Code, P_Id1, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try `SELECT tabl1.Id1 INTO Id1...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
with t as 
   (SELECT Id1 as New_Id1, Code as New_code) 
   FROM tabl1)
select New_Id1 into Id1 
from t
WHERE New_code = Code;
```

Another solution is this one:

```
execute immediate 'select Id1 from tabl1 where Code = :b' into Id1 using Code;
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do anything for it, this is why standards are made, for variable declarations.
one of it is, an `PL/SQL` variable should be prefixed with `l_` (local) or `g_` (global)

database end up with ambiguity in judging which of the operand (left or right) is a db column or a variable.

Also to add some more light, any variable used in a query, will be treated as a `bind variable implicitly.`

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

1. The [`VARCHAR` datatype should not be used](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50978) and `VARCHAR2` should be used in its place - `VARCHAR` is currently synonymous with `VARCHAR2` however the VARCHAR data type is scheduled to be redefined as a separate data type used for variable-length character strings compared with different comparison semantics (i.e. for `VARCHAR2` an empty string is equivalent to a `NULL` value but when `VARCHAR` is redefined then an empty `VARCHAR` will not be equivalent to `NULL`).
2. You do not specify sizes for datatypes in the header of a procedure - so if you are going to declare the inputs as named datatypes then you just need to use `VARCHAR2` and not `VARCHAR(50)`.

   - You can instead refer to the `%TYPE` of a table's column - so `tabl1.code%TYPE` and `tabl1.id1%TYPE`.
3. You do not need to initialise Id1 - this will be done by the `SELECT` statement (and if you require an exception handler then you can define it in there as required).
4. You ought to have an exception handler.

Something like:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/03645/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE INTE IS OBJECT( x NUMBER(3), y NUMBER(3) )
/

CREATE TABLE tabl1 (
  code VARCHAR2(50),
  id1  INTE
)
/

INSERT INTO tabl1 VALUES ( 'a', INTE( 3, 4 ) )
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedval (
  code IN  tabl1.code%TYPE,
  Id1  OUT tabl1.id1%TYPE
)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT t.Id1
  INTO   Id1
  FROM   tabl1 t
  WHERE  t.Code = code;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    Id1 := NULL;
END;
/
```